# Retaining MVVM Viewmodel state through configuration changes: use Fragment or ViewModel class?

Tags: android, mvvm, persistence

I'm rewriting a simple application to use the MVVM architecture. I got everything working, except retaining state when the user rotates the screen (or any configuration change for that matter).

While doing research I've come across several options, but I can't figure out which one is right (if there even is only one "right" way).

1. (onSaveInstanceState: can't be used in the ViewModel, this only works in activities/fragments)
2. Extending the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) class. This is apparently made to make it easier to store UI-related data across the lifecycle. I find it quite confusing, and it seems overkill for what my app does. There are no async requests to online databases, feeds, or whatsoever. More than that: I can't use @Bindable anymore, so I don't know how to make the binding with my View.
3. Using fragments to persist state. This is used in Google's own [todo-mvvm-databinding sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/9ec06d0595bdb0aa19c7e1ca59d9548c52f72694/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/addedittask/AddEditTaskActivity.java#L112). I find it strange to use Fragments for this. They don't seem to be made for the purpose of just storing data.

Which one is the "best"? And why?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090

Comment: @BhavikMakwana  this already helped a lot with understanding ViewModel, but I don't see how I could use that class without having to use all the LiveData stuff. Is that possible?